# My visual studio 2005 solution sometimes does not open the entire projects

Tags: visual-studio-2005

My visual studio 2005 solution sometimes does not open the entire projects. To clarify what I mean by the “Entire projects”, my application is consisting of different layers such as DAO, Domain, Service, Utility and finally Web.App that contains all of my .aspx, .asxc and code behind files. Each layer consists of large amount of .CS and .VB classes. So, when I open the solution file (.sln), it only opens the Web.App project without opening the others.

Has anybody encountered this kind of issue in VS2005 and if you have had what you did to fix it, please let me know. So, basically when I open the project .sln, it only shows the Web.App project not the other projects. This does not happen all the time, but happens once in a while.

Is it because Visual Studio 2005 was not installed correctly or missing some updates? Any ideas or suggestions are highly appreciated. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a new solution and adding all the relevant projects to see if perhaps your current .sln is corrupt?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this one is really large project , it is going to take me quite a long time to add all the missing projects.However, if nothing works out, this might be the option.